# generating functions closed form

Tags: generating-functions

I am very new to using generating functions and am trying to apply one here.
Is there a nice closed form for the expression $$\sum \frac{x^n}{1-x^n}$$
For example. $\sum x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Answer (score 4):

It is a Lambert series:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n} = \sum_{m\geq 1}d(m)\,x^m$$
where $d(m)$ is the divisor function.

Answer (score 4):

This post elaborates the answer given by **Jack D'Aurizio**.

Note that 
$$\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}=\frac{1}{1-x^n}-1=\left( 1+x^n+x^{2n}+x^{3n}+\dotsc \right)-1=x^n+x^{2n}+x^{3n}+\dotsc$$ using the sum for the geometric series (which, according to your post, you already know).

Your function now just sums up these terms over all $n$.

If we want to find out the coefficient of $x^m$ in your function, we have to examine in which of the summands such a term appears. That is, when $n|m$.

Hence, the coefficient of $x^m$ in your function is exactly the number of positive divisors of $m$, also denoted $d(m)$.

Comment: You euphemistically wrote: "This post elaborates the answer given by..." but that was clearly a non-answer. You gave the real answer which deserved an accept by the OP. Getting an accept from an OP helps by upvoting the question. I mean why answer a question you don't value?